# Software to playback voice recordings with adjustable speed and voice normalization

Tags: windows, audio, media-player, audio-recording, voice-recording

Can anyone recommend an application to listen to hundreds of voice recordings?  Here is the functionality desired:

1. Windows 7 compatible
2. Must be able to *quickly* and *easily* change the speed of the recording.  A dial to adjust the speed, or a similar UI, is important.  The ability to quickly restore the speed to normal (100%) is also important.  I have been using VLC and it's not bad, but it's rather clumsy for this use.  I am open to skins for VLC that would make it more suitable.
3. Strongly prefer (but not a requirement) for the software to auto-adjust the pitch of voices at different speeds so they sound somewhat normal.  I think VLC is supposed to be doing this, but it doesn't work well, as the voice pitch changes significantly as the playback speed is adjusted.
4. Strongly prefer (but not a requirement) for the software to be able to quickly jump backwards/forwards 5 seconds at a time.
5. Gratis

Comment: Maybe audacity?